# How does one type archaic kana on the phone using the typical kana keyboard?

Tags: katakana

It’s not something that happens often, but if I wanted to type on my phone something like ヱビスビール, what would be the best way to do it using the kana keyboard built into the iPhone.  Is it impossible to directly write these archaic kana?  The only way I can seem to do it is rely on the predictive auto complete (変換) to know the familiar usage of word that contain the archaic kana.

Comment: https://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/129/1129154/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @naruto mentioned, typing the string きゅうかな in the iOS Japanese keyboard will bring up a list of obsolete kana in the selection list.

Comment: That software in iOS does not have any shorter way? Software installed in my computer supports **wyi** for ゐ・ヰ and **wye** for ゑ・ヱ.